# Userscript - Replace another Javascript before it executes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts, tampermonkey

I want to create my own Userscript for Tampermonkey for a specific site I often use and I want to add some features and I want to improve some things.

Since it loads some .js files, that do some stuff I don't want to happen, I want to replace these .js files and reimplement the things I need within my Userscript.

**I don't want to replace functions**, I want to completely remove specific .js files from the DOM **before** they get executed and reimplement them in my Userscript to my preferences.

I tried to use this method: http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/125936
But it didn't work at all, no errormessages or similar, it just doesn't execute the Eventlistener, I use Chrome, could it be that this has to be implemented in another way for Chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`beforescriptexecute` event referenced in your question isn't implemented in Chrome and probably [never will be](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/bChX6leKqtg/Idut6cE4ORcJ).

There is no way for a userscript in Chrome to prevent some webpage script that is referenced in the page html `<script>` tag from loading.

The only solution is to use an extension that blocks urls via [webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

- If you don't mind making your userscript dependent on another extension then use [HTTP Request Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-request-blocker/eckpjmeijpoipmldfbckahppeonkoeko), [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) and others.
- For a complete solution without dependencies you'll have to make your own extension, not a userscript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, since I already use AdBlock I simply created a filter to block the JS, I just hoped I could do this independent from other extensions, but it's not that much of a big deal, I'll create a specific Filterlist for Adblock on my Github which I can include on all of my machines where I intend to use this script, so it's not that much of a hassle.